# Multiple RDLC to Single word document on separate page

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc, rdlc, dynamic-rdlc-generation

I Have 4-5 RDLC which i want to write in Word Document.
I have converted every RDLC to byte array then i am combining two byte array to single byte array but memory stream writing only first array.
Can anyone assist here ?
Please find below code which i am trying

```
    {
         byte[] FirstLetter = DownloadFirstLetter(assigneeId);  //First RDLC to byte[]
        
         byte[] SecondLetter = DownloadSecondLetter(assigneeId);//Second RDLC to byte[]
        
         MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream();            
         byte[] t = Combine(FirstLetter , SecondLetter );
         stream.Write(t, 0, t.Length);
         stream.Position = 0;
        
        using (FileStream file = new FileStream(mDesPath + fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    {
                        stream.WriteTo(file);
                    }
        }


public static byte[] Combine(byte[] first, byte[] second)
                {
                    byte[] bytes = new byte[first.Length + second.Length];
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(first, 0, bytes, 0, first.Length);
                    Buffer.BlockCopy(second, 0, bytes, first.Length, second.Length);
                    return bytes;
                }
```

Comment: You are writing second file to position zero of the buffer instead of to the end.  Using a List<byte> makes it easy to add to the end.

Comment: Thanks for replying @jdweng, it could be better if you give any example or code.

Comment: List<byte> bytes = new List<byte(); bytes.Add(first); bytes.Add(second);